# Azure Portal Application in AD says certificate is expired even after I have updated it

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, certificate

My AD application certificate expired and I have put a new one in and deleted all the old expired ones, however when I go to the application it still shows it as expired

Comment: The correct answer depends on details that are not in your question. Start with what application and how it is configured to retrieve certificates. Some applications will need to be restarted.

Comment: It can be due to caching, try Ctrl+F5?

Answer (score 0):

You could follow the steps below to create a new certificate credential for your AD App.

1.Run the PowerShell command in local, change the `-FilePath` to what you want.

```
$cert=New-SelfSignedCertificate -Subject "CN=TodoListDaemonWithCert" -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\CurrentUser\My"  -KeyExportPolicy Exportable -KeySpec Signature
Export-Certificate -Cert $cert -FilePath C:\Users\joyw\Desktop\user1234.cer
```

2.Navigate to the `Azure Active Directory` in the portal -> your AD App -> `Certificates & secrets` -> `Upload certificate`.

[image]

---

Or if you don't want to upload the certificate manually, you could use the powrshell script as below, after running the script, refresh the portal, you will find it works fine. Make sure you install the [`Az`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-3.1.0) module.

```
Connect-AzAccount
$cert=New-SelfSignedCertificate -Subject "CN=TodoListDaemonWithCert" -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\CurrentUser\My"  -KeyExportPolicy Exportable -KeySpec Signature
$binCert = $cert.GetRawCertData()
$credValue = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($binCert)
New-AzADAppCredential -ApplicationId <application-id of the AD App> -CertValue $credValue -StartDate $cert.NotBefore -EndDate $cert.NotAfter
```